# Why does the last if statement print when the condition is false

Tags: python

Why does "Invalid Operator" print when the if statement is false? Could I use an elif statement to make it work?

```
num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
operator = input("Enter your operator here: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter your second number here: "))


if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)

if operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
if operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
if operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
if operator != ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
    print("Invalid Operator.")
```

Comment: What do you think `operator != ("+", "-", "*", "/")` means and why?

Comment: `operator` isn't equal to that tuple, that's why. You probably meant to use `not in` instead of `!=`. (But an `if/elif/else` chain is probably most normal here.)

Comment: That last condition should probably be `if operator not in '+-*/':`

Comment: What `else` statement?

Comment: Try to use 'not in' instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 3):

You are compairing an `operator` to a tuple. Instead, you can check if `operator` in tuple, like this:

```
if operator not in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
    print("Invalid Operator.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is `elif`s:

```
if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Operator.")
```

With this, when you add a new operator you don't need to modify the `not in (...)` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The last if-statement is not correct. Now it checks if it is equal to the entire tuple. You could check if the operator is not in the list.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
operator = input("Enter your operator here: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter your second number here: "))


if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
if operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
if operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
if operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
if operator not in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
    print("Invalid Operator.")
```

Another option is indeed using elif and else. If it’s not one of the first for options, then in will be an Invalid Operator (else).

```
if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Operator.")
```

*Edit: Changed* `if not in ...` *from list to tuple. Tuples are more efficient in this context.*

Comment: `in []` is the not the right way of doing it.

Comment: Your right. I tested both out and using a tuble instead of a list is about twice as fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
operator != ("+", "-", "*", "/") # condition_1
```

where `operator` is a string object, where as `("+", "-", "*", "/")` is a tuple so both are not equal so above condition_1 result into `True` and last `if block` will get executed.
Either use if/elif/else statement or change last condition correctly like this

```
operator not in ("+", "-", "*", "/") # itemwise ckech takeplace 
operator not in "+-*/" # string is also a iterable object
```